# MVVM Set MenuItem's DataContext

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datacontext, menuitem

I have a ListView with an ItemSource from a List of string.
Now I have added a context menu which should just implement some commands. But the problem ist how to set the DataContext. Found some solutions but none of these worked for me. Dont know where my fault ist.

Here my XAML code, reduced to the important regions.

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstBackups" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedClient.Backups}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Do Something"                                           DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                      cinch:SingleEventCommand.RoutedEventName="MouseLeftButtonUp"
                                      cinch:SingleEventCommand.TheCommandToRun="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenBackupInExplorerCommand, ElementName=UserControl}">
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: It will be hard to help you when you don't post post hat you oreads have tried. Post your viewModel code, you can try using snoop to see the binding error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you've noticed that the ContextMenu is not part of the same visual tree as your user control (annoying I know).  So you have to get a bit creative with your binding logic.

Try changing the command binding to the following

```
cinch:SingleEventCommand.TheCommandToRun="{BindingPath=PlacementTarget.DataContext.OpenBackupInExplorerCommand, 
                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                                          AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
```

That should attempt to get the DataContext of the placement target (in your case the ListView) which should inherit the DataContext of the UserControl

Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Guess this works to set the MenuItem's DataContext to ContextMenu's DataContext. But the DataContext of the ContextMenu is still System.String.
I tried to set it on the ContextMenu with
    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DataContext}">
But this still doesnt work for me. Now is DataContext object.null